# Mixing Asp.net default validation with a custum submit action

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I have a page whose submit buttton does dot submit at all. It rathers has a some javascript in OnClientClick that employs some logic and redirects the user to a calculated URL. The thing is I want to use ASP.net default validation in this setup. I need to be able to query the state of the client side validation in the javascript. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be what your looking for, [using ASP.NET Validation from client code](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/13/using-asp-net-validation-from-client-code.aspx)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddEntry" runat="server" OnClientClick="ValidateAndAddNewEntry(); return false;" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="AddEntry" Text="Create" />
```

JavaScript

```
function ValidateAndAddNewEntry()  {

var res = Page_ClientValidate("AddEntry");   
    if ( res == true )  
    {  
        //Do work  
    }  
}
```